# PSU operational temperature

Tags: power-supply, temperature

What exactly happens if the operational temperature is exceeded and the psu has OTP protection ?
Does the psu stop immediately or functions but at a lower efficiency or the continuous output falls ?

Comment: Some brief searching seems to suggest when OTP is triggered, it'll turn off; it won't function at a reduced capacity.

Answer (score 1):

From [Coolermaster](https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/what-are-the-definitions-of-ovp-opp-ocp-scp-otp-and-bop/)

> **OTP (Over Temperature Protection)**: Shuts down the power supply when the internal temperature exceeds the maximum safe operating temperature.

That seems pretty clear. It will simply switch off.

You very probably wouldn't want a PSU to drop to lower voltages or even ampages. That may be somewhat chaotic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply